# regex expression for replace method

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract the year in ( ) for a given title

Example:

"This is 40 (2012)"

returns: "This is 40"

```
title = mTitle.replace(/[^a-zA-Z:\s]/g, '');
```

This works except for titles that also have a number before the parenthesis.
I'm also trying to get the year.

```
year = mTitle.replace(/\D+/g, '');
```

I having a trouble wrapping my mind around it.

Answer (score 4):

To remove trailing year(digits) surrounded by parentheses:

```
> "This is 40 (2012)".replace(/\(\d+\)$/, '')
"This is 40 "
```

To also remove spaces before year part:

```
> "This is 40 (2012)".replace(/\s*\(\d+\)$/, '')
"This is 40"
```

Comment: That works great. What about just the year inside the parentheses?

Comment: @MickB, I don't understand what do you mean. Do you want get `2012` from `This is 40 (2012)`?

Comment: @MickB, Try `"This is 40 (2012)".match(/\((\d+)\)$/)[1]`. This give you `"2004"`

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing with the year and I am getting all the numbers instead of just the year in the paranethses

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of these options :

```
var year = 'This is 40 (2012)'.slice(-5, -1);
var year = 'This is 40 (2012)'.match(/\d+(?=.$)/)[0];
// regex : one or more digits followed by any char + end of string
var year = 'This is 40 (2012)'.replace(/^.*?(\d+).$/, '$1');
// regex : zero or more chars + one or more digits ($1) + any char
```

Doc : [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [regular expressions](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml).